# Translate flowchart to c++ code

Tags: c++, flowchart, control-structure

I have a problem translating this flowchart below to C++ code.

[image: Flowchart]

It should probably look somewhat like this (I know it's wrong for now):

```
do {
  I1;
  if(!W1) {
      I2;
  ...
  }
}
```

`I1`, `I2`, `I3` are instructions. I think I should use boolean variables to do it correctly, but how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a loop in the flow chart. The condition for stopping the loop is in fact W1.

```
while (!W1())
{
}
```

I1 is executed (initially) regardless, and is performed before the loop finish condition check, so let's update the code:

```
I1();
while (!W1())
{
}
```

Again, I2 is performed uncoditionally:

```
I1();
while (!W1())
{              
   I2();
}
```

Now, W2 affects whether we execute I1 or I3, let's update the code accordingly:

```
I1();  // for the first, unconditional execution
while (!W1())
{
   I2();
   if (W2())
      I1();
   else
      I3();
}
```

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are in the case of two crossed loops: neither is nested into the other one, so the usual flow control tools are insufficient.
Many will usually model them with artificial boolean flags, or duplicate part of the code. But this is actually one of the very few (and I do mean *very few* -- think hard beforehand) use cases of `goto`.

Ignoring `W2`'s `true` branch, this looks like a simple `while` loop:

```
I1;

while(!W1) {
    I2;

    if(W2)
        /* ? */;

    I3;
}
```

Now just add the missing branch. The label, of course, should be adequately named to reflect your actual domain logic. Add comments so it's crystal clear, and you're all set.

```
    // Let's W1 a stuff from our list of stuffs

handleNextStuff:

    // Take a stuff
    I1;

    // Try W1'ing the stuff.
    while(!W1) {
        I2;

        // No way we can W1 this stuff, drop it and try the next one.
        if(W2)
            goto handleNextStuff;

        // A step closer to a W1'd stuff.
        I3;
    }
```

Comment: Albeit this looks like a convenient case for using `goto`, introducing it for (most likely) a newbie programmer, may lead to future problems... Just imagine the consequences if someone decided to encapsulate the `while`'s body within a function.

Comment: @hauron Added some more caution to my wording. If the loop makes sense as a separate function, then that function will have two possible return states, which will be documented and plugged back into the "outer" loop. In fact, another way people work around using `goto` is spawning extraneous functions from which they can return early -- but if the function has an actual reason to exist on its own, then there's no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea:

```
for (bool skip_i1 = false; ; skip_i1 = true)
{
    for (bool w2 = true; w2; w2 = W2())
    {
        if (!skip_i1) { I1(); }
        skip_i1 = false;

        if (W1()) { Finish(); return; }

        I2();
    }

    I3();
}
```

There are two loops in the flow chart, so we have two loops in the code, but because the control flow is "mis-nested", we need a flag (`skip_i1`) to branch on the overlapping bit. As a variation, you could put `skip_i1 = false;` into the inner `for` incrementor, or into an `else` branch of the `if` statement.

I assume that the entire code lives in a function of its own (as it better had!), so that we can exit the inner loop directly with `return`.

Answer (score 0):

```
START:
I1();
while(!W1){
    I2();
    while(W2) // or if() it's the same...
        goto START;
    I3();
}
return; // finish
```

I hope it help